# Migrating DDL from Cassandra to YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to migrate DDLs from apache cassandra to YugabyteDB YCQL . But I am getting this error:

```
cassandra@ycqlsh:killrvideo> CREATE TABLE killrvideo.videos (
              ...                   video_id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
              ...                   added_date timestamp,
              ...                   title text
              ...               ) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p'
              ...                   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
              ...                   AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
              ...                   AND cdc = false
              ...                   AND comment = ''
              ...                   AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
              ...                   AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
              ...                   AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
              ...                   AND default_time_to_live = 0
              ...                   AND extensions = {}
              ...                   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
              ...                   AND max_index_interval = 2048
              ...                   AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
              ...                   AND min_index_interval = 128
              ...                   AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
              ...                   AND speculative_retry = '99p';
SyntaxException: Invalid SQL Statement. syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting SCONST
CREATE TABLE killrvideo.videos (
                  video_id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
                  added_date timestamp,
                  title text
              ) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p'
                  AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
                  AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
                  AND cdc = false
                  AND comment = ''
                  AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
                  AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
                  AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
                  AND default_time_to_live = 0
                  AND extensions = {}
                  ^
                  AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
                  AND max_index_interval = 2048
                  AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
                  AND min_index_interval = 128
                  AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
                  AND speculative_retry = '99p';
 (ql error -11)
```

Are these optional parameters after the create table not supported in YugabyteDB (pulled from describing keyspace killrvideo).
Not sure what I am missing here? Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_create_table/#table-properties-1
You can remove everything starting from `with` which will probably allow you to create the table.

Taking this statement from the docs:

> The other YCQL table properties are allowed in the syntax but are
> currently ignored internally (have no effect). (other are properties
> that do not deal with a limited set of table properties for the YCQL
> engine)

The probable reason you are getting this error is that you use properties that are specific to stock cassandra, and are not implemented in YugabyteDB, because they use a different storage layer.